# Eclipse Indigo refactory bug

Tags: eclipse

I have recently moved to Indigo and Mercurial. When I tried to move a file to a different package using the ‘move’ function in Eclipse, it did not update the references. So in the moved file, the package name is still the old package. I got tons of red lines now because of it.

Is this an indigo bug? Or does it have anything to do with Mercurial? It used to update the reference when I was using the older version Eclipse+svn.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: oops, a typo, should be refactor